# C# - Repository / UnitOfWork - Prevent access to Repository directly

Tags: c#

I'm creating a generic UnitOfWork, Repository pattern.

**** I know it's far for complete, but showing this code takes less space :-) ****

I have the following generic *IRepository*

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    #region Methods

    TEntity GetById(int id);

    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    #endregion
}
```

And off course, I do have an implementation of this:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    #region Constructors

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    #endregion

    #region IRepository Members

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

As a next point, I do have the *IUnitOfWork*:
The IUnitOfWork interface has a single member, Commit().

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    #region Methods

    void Commit();

    #endregion
}
```

Then I do have the implementation for this one:

```
public abstract class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Constructors

    protected UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    protected DbContext Context { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region IUnitOfWork Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, the idea is the following:

I do have a class representing a single entity in the database:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then do have the repository which is using this entity:

```
public class Repository<Person> : Repository<Person> where Person : class
{
    public Repository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

And then I have my unit of work, which creates the repositories:

```
public class TestUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork
{
    public TestUnitOfWork(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        PersonRepository = new Repository<Person>(context);
    }

    public Repository<Person> PersonRepository { get; set; } 
}
```

But I do have an issue with this code, it's working perfectly, I can do:

I can do work with the repositories through the UnitOfWork:

```
new TestUnitOfWork(new DbContext("")).PersonRepository.Insert(new Person());
```

But, I can also work directly on the repositories:

```
new Repository<Person>(new DbContext("")).Insert(new Person());
```

This is something which I would like to avoid. I want the user to be only working with the repositories through the unit of work object.

I've tought to change the constructor to internal but that doesn't solve the issue when you're method accessing the database is in the same project as the repository itself.

Is there any way to restrict all kind of access to the repository and force the user through the unit of work?

Comment: Do other classes need the person repository? If not you could make it a private class inside your `TestUnitOfWork` which might potentially do what you want (I've not really used child classes much so not sure if the accessibility would work perfectly).

Comment: I don't think, the forcing users to this practice is good idea. User can have regular reason to use repository directly. If you want force this practice in you project, you should have conventions and (optionaly) static code analysis.

Comment: @TcKs Do you mean that there is no way to restrict the access to the repository directly?

Comment: At least, user can always use reflection to use/instantiate the classes. So in fact, without extreme complex hiding types in nested classes and playing with CAS, you never 100% forbid the access to repository from code of same assembly.

Comment: @Complexity: in general if class A (TestUnitOfWork) can create an instance of class B (repository) then class C in the same assembly as class A can also create an instance of class B. The only time I can think of that this might not be true is for private child classes as I commented. There is certainly nothing you could decorate class B with that would allow class A to create it but not class B.

Comment: It's not my intention to hide it in all the possible cases, but I want to avoid an easy way to use the repository directly;

Comment: @Complexity: What would you consider an easy way? You could make it not able to be created via `new` by using factory methods. It might be less easy since you have to know about the factory but its not going to stop anybody who really wants to use it.

Comment: I know for example that through reflection you might be able to create instances, is that what you mean by factory methods? T